# Report Viewer not printing or exporting in landscape format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, report

I created a report and set the width to 11in and the height to 8.5 and when the report loads it is in landscape but when I print it or export it, it is in portrait size? Is there somewhere else I need to modify size settings?

Comment: I got it working I found additional settings in the report menu

Answer (score 1):

You can specify it by the user interface in a reports properties.

[image: Report Properties]

---

Alternatively, you can also specify the landscape property by code like so:

```
ReportViewer1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working I found additional settings in the report menu